# The grub2-mkconfig does not propagate renamed root logical volume on RHEL 9

Tags: rhel, kernel, grub2-mkconfig

On the RHEL 9.3 I have renamed the logical volume (LV) `/dev/lvm01/root` to `/dev/lvm01/root.vol`. I did everything to make the new name correctly recognized:

- changed `/etc/fstab` entry
- reloaded systemd configuration
- remounted /

And I also modified the `/etc/default/grub` entry:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol ro crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M resume=/dev/mapper/lvm01-swap.vol rd.lvm.lv=lvm01/root.vol rd.lvm.lv=lvm01/swap.vol"
```

Then I expected the `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to do the rest of the job and rebooted. But the system ended up with dracut message that the root partition is not found (or something like that).

After short investigation, I realized the kernel parameters had not been modified as expected. The manual change helped to get the OS booted. Interesting that the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` was updated. But what was not updated was the `/boot/loader/entries/*` files. And it was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the temporary solution seemed to be

```
# grub2-mkconfig --update-bls-cmdline -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

But it only fixed the actual state. The update of kernel still used the previous LV name.

The only solution which helped also for kernel updates seems to be `grubby`:

```
# grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="root=/dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol ro crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M resume=/dev/mapper/lvm01-swap.vol rd.lvm.lv=lvm01/root.vol rd.lvm.lv=lvm01/swap.vol"
```

Even after the kernel update, the content of new conf file in the `/boot/loader/entries/<machine-id>-<kernel version>.conf` looks good and the system boot is fine.

In fact, the problem may be related to this RH ticket, which is opened for quite a some time (but I'm not sure):
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RHEL-4313